# SSRS Sunburst chart: is there an action option for inner ring and possibility to mimic a fisheye?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have SSRS 2016 and I want to implement sunburst chart with possibility to `drillthrough` existing rings.

Basically I'm staring with 2 levels chart. 
- for Series properties I set `Go to Report` action
- it does jump to inner report but only from outer ring
- no active cursor in inner ring appears - tooltip is shown only

Is there a possibility to achieve active cursor in inner ring(s)?

Another question is there some workaround to mimic a fisheye in the center of the sunburst chart, e.g. to go back to the parent report? 
I tried to put a text box with action expression within, but it does not allow to overlay it with the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to add a new **Chart Title** to the chart and use the **Custom Position** properties to put it in the center of your sunburst.

Set the Custom Position's Enabled property to TRUE. Then use the Height and Width properties to adjust the size of the Title and the Left and Top to position it.

You could also use a Background Image on the Title to use instead of text.

The Chart Title will let you have an ACTION so you can create the link to go back to the main report.

Comment: thank you, Hannover Fist! Title adding successfully resloved button placing on a chart. As for sunburst rings issue eventually we decided to go with tree chart instead to show hierarchy.